# Randomly space characters throughout string?

Tags: javascript, string

To shuffle a string, I could use something like this

```
String.prototype.shuffle = function () {
    var arr = this.split("");
    var len = arr.length;
    for (var n = len - 1; n > 0; n--) {
        m = Math.floor(Math.random() * (n + 1));
        tmp = arr[n];
        arr[n] = arr[m];
        arr[m] = tmp;
    }
    return arr.join("");
}
```

But how could I randomly space it with `n` characters, while preserving the string order?

For example:

```
"test"   =>   "t-es--t"
"test"   =>   "-t-e-st"
"test"   =>   "te--st-"
```

I've thought about creating a list from the string, generating a random number to represent an index, and then shifting the list to the left, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Add some extra spaces to the end of the string, then shuffle it.

Comment: The characters will also be shuffled. It could turn `"fox "` into `"fx o"`. @Barmar

Comment: Ahh, misread the question.

Comment: ?! what on earth for? (besides an academic exercise)

Comment: Part of a special encryption. @JasonS

Comment: If it's part of an encryption scheme, you should be careful to specify what you mean by "random". Beware of half-assed encryption schemes; and be aware that most built-in random number generators have severe shortcomings from both a statistical and cryptographic standpoint.

Comment: If you want each possible output to be equally likely (unbiased generation), you're looking for a  random partition generator. I can't remember how to do this, and a quick look on google doesn't seem to show a relevant reference, but that's what you want to look for. Whichever random generator you use has to have enough state bits to be adequate, otherwise some possibilities are not possible at all and others are more likely to occur. The number of possibilities are given by [combinatorics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts).

Comment: It won't be protecting any significant pieces of information. So "random" doesn't have to be quite so random. Just enough to not be discernibly legible when used with the rest of my encryption. @JasonS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will insert `n` characters `char` randomly into the string.  If `char` is missing, it defaults to a space:

```
String.prototype.shuffle = function(n, char) {
  var arr = this.split(''),
      char= char || ' ';

  while(n--) {
    arr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr.length+1)), 0, char);
  }

  return arr.join('');
} //shuffle
```

This **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3cghurg/)** shows the relative random distribution using the method.

Comment: nice! distribution check makes this believable.

Comment: ...although the use of mutative methods in a functional `forEach()` callback should qualify as undefined behavior that makes computers explode. Methinks better to have a regular old imperative `for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i)`. Also, there's only one degree of freedom here... there should be `n` spaces added to a string of length `L`, not `n` spaces added to a string of length `n`.

Comment: @JasonS, thanks, I misread the question regarding `n` spaces.  Also, whether mutating the array within the `forEach()` is undefined or not, it was non-intuitive, and a loop makes more sense.  (I chose `while` instead of `for`).  Updated!

Answer (score 2):

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7xf3zxxm/3/)

Even though I loved @Barmar 's idea.. 
You can do it by simply looping and randomizing positions to insert the spaces..

```
String.prototype.insertSpaces = function (n, char) {
    var str = this;
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
        var randPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (str.length + 1)); // get random index to insert
        str = str.substring(0, randPos) + char + str.substring(randPos, str.legnth); // insert the repeated sting
    }  
    return str;        
}
```

Comment: This tends to generate the majority of the inserted characters consecutively.

Comment: @ZachGates I guess you are right, the more characters in the original string the less chances the randomly inserted spaces will be consecutive.. My method greatly increases the chances for that.. you can skip the `rand` variable and inset a single one each time to a randomized position

Comment: @ZachGates Glad to help! Thanks for the heads up about the consecutive chars - (no need for the old function)

Comment: Not sure why, but this doesn't seem to give a good random distribution:   "t____est" comes up three times more often than "____test":  http://jsfiddle.net/17L1bp1a/1/

Comment: There's an off-by-one error here. It should be `var randPos = Math.round(Math.random() * (str.length+1));` Otherwise, I think this might produce a uniform distribution. In which case it's much simpler than my answer.

Comment: @JasonS, becuase we are using `.round()` the final value can be also rounded up.. in that case the char will be added to the end of the string. Take an example of a 5 letter string, the index of the first letter is 0 and the index of the last one is 4. `round(random * 5)` gives values beween 0 and 5 (including both) so this is exactly what we need. Adding 1 here will make both `randPos = 6` and `randPos = 5` insert the new value at the end - hurting uniformity as you suggested.

Comment: Don't use `round()`, use `floor()`. (I missed seeing that.) The `round()` function will not provide a uniform distribution. since only the input (0 - 0.5) will provide a `randPos` of 0, whereas the subsequent intervals (0.5 - 1.5), (1.5 - 2.5), etc. have a length of 1.

Comment: Thanks @JasonS, you are right. updated the answer. floor(random *  (n+1)) instead of round

Answer (score 2):

If you want a truly unbiased solution that produces all possibilities equally likely, and have access to a perfect random number generator (which is a whole other topic), there's a fairly easy solution. Let's define some terms:

- `m` = number of characters in the string
- `k` = number of spaces you want to insert (you called this `n`)

Consider one solution to this problem with m=7 and k=3:

```
0123456789
cab ba g e
```

What the problem essentially amounts to is choosing `k` different numbers from among a set of `m+k` numbers. There are `(m+k)!/(m!*k!)` possibilities. This is the concept of [combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) and is similar to the stars-and-bars problem in the Wikipedia page. (To get an unbiased generator you would need a random number generator with the number of state values much higher than this number of possibilities. But I said RNGs are a whole other topic.)

Here's an example in Python showing *all* possibilities:

```
import itertools

def show_all(s, k):
    # show all combinations of k spaces inserted into string s
    m = len(s)
    for sample in itertools.combinations(range(m+k),k):
        jprev = 0
        out = ''
        for ispace, i in enumerate(sample):
            j = i-ispace    # adjust index by number of spaces used
            out += s[jprev:j] + ' '
            jprev = j
        out += s[jprev:]
        yield sample, out

for sample, out in show_all('shoe',2):
    print sample,':'+out+':'
```

output:

```
(0, 1) :  shoe:
(0, 2) : s hoe:
(0, 3) : sh oe:
(0, 4) : sho e:
(0, 5) : shoe :
(1, 2) :s  hoe:
(1, 3) :s h oe:
(1, 4) :s ho e:
(1, 5) :s hoe :
(2, 3) :sh  oe:
(2, 4) :sh o e:
(2, 5) :sh oe :
(3, 4) :sho  e:
(3, 5) :sho e :
(4, 5) :shoe  :
```

Now the problem becomes one of generating a random combination. In Python this is part of the [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
def random_combination_with_replacement(iterable, r):
    "Random selection from itertools.combinations_with_replacement(iterable, r)"
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    indices = sorted(random.randrange(n) for i in xrange(r))
    return tuple(pool[i] for i in indices))
```

In Javascript we have to implement this ourselves, which we can do using [Robert Floyd's algorithm for sampling without replacement](http://www.nowherenearithaca.com/2013/05/robert-floyds-tiny-and-beautiful.html):

pseudocode:

```
initialize set S to empty
for J := N-M + 1 to N do
  T := RandInt(1, J)
  if T is not in S then
    insert T in S
  else
    insert J in S
```

Javascript:

```
function random_comb(r, n, m)
{
   /* Generate a combination of m distinct random integers between 0 and n-1
      using Floyd's algorithm

      r: random generation function
         such that r(k) generates an integer in the range [0, k-1]
    */
   var S = {};
   var out = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < m; ++i)
   {
      var j = i+(n-m);
      var t = r(j+1);
      var item = (t in S) ? j : t;
      S[item] = 1;
      out.push(item);
   }
   return out.sort();
}
```

Now let's put it all together, ignoring the fact that Math.random() is inadequate:

```js
var r = function(n) { return Math.floor(Math.random()*n); }
function random_comb(r, n, m)
{
  /* Generate a combination of m distinct random integers between 0 and n-1
          using Floyd's algorithm

          r: random generation function
             such that r(k) generates an integer in the range [0, k-1]
        */
  var S = {};
  var out = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < m; ++i)
  {
    var j = i+(n-m);
    var t = r(j+1);
    var item = (t in S) ? j : t;
    S[item] = 1;
    out.push(item);
  }
  return out.sort();
}
function random_insert(r, s, k, c)
{
  /* randomly insert k instances of character c into string s */
  var m = s.length;
  var S = random_comb(r, m+k, k);
  var jprev = 0;
  var out = '';
  for (var ispace = 0; ispace < k; ++ispace)
  {
    var i = S[ispace];
    var j = i - ispace;   // adjust index by # of spaces
    out += s.slice(jprev,j) + c;
    jprev = j;
  }
  out += s.slice(jprev);
  return out;
}

var word = 'shoe';
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
  results.push(random_insert(r,word, 2, '-'));
}
var tally = {};
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
{
  var s = random_insert(r,word,2,'-');
  tally[s] = (s in tally) ? (tally[s] + 1) : 1;
}
for (var s in tally)
{
  results.push(s+": "+tally[s]);
}
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i)
{
  $("#results").append(results[i]+'<br>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: correct but verbose, some of the other answers are simpler.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addRandomSpaces(str,n,char){
    for (var newstr="", i=0; i<str.length;){
        if (n && Math.random()<0.5) {
            newstr += char;
            n--;
        } else {
            newstr += str[i++];
        }
    }
    while(n--){
        newstr += char;
    }
    return newstr;
}
```

Here's a function that will loop through a given string `str`, adding `n` instances of `char` at random places. If when it finishes, `n` items haven't been added, it adds finishes them at the end.

Comment: Downvoted: this is heavily biased towards adding spaces at the beginning of a long string, or towards the end of a short string.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.prototype.addspace = function () {
var arr = this.split("");
var len = arr.length;
maxSp = 4;
for(var i = 0; i <= len; i++){
    m = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxSp + 1));
    for(var j = 0; j < m ; j++){
        arr.splice(i,0," ");
    }
    len += m;
    i +=m;
}
return arr.join("");
```

}
alert("Juanito".addspace().shuffle());

Comment: This will also shuffle the characters.

Comment: Check Now. @ZachGates

Answer (score 0):

You can use the slice function insert the new character:

```
var x = "this is phrase";
var y = " a";
[x.slice(0,7), y, x.slice(7)].join('');
Result: this is a phrase
```

Something like this:

```
String.prototype.shuffle2 = function() {
  'use strict';
  var numberOfSpaces = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.length - 1));
  var word = this;
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfSpaces; i++) {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.length - 1));
    word = [word.slice(0,index), '-', word.slice(index)].join('');
  }
  return word;
};
```

Greetings!